# not able to open dialog in jquery moblie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am unable to open a dialog if it exist on the same page.

I tried it with:

`$("#addDialog").dialog('open');`

Then I tried it with an click event on the button `$("#openAddDlg")`

```
  $.mobile.changePage('#addDialog', {
      transition: 'pop',
      changeHash: true,
      role: 'dialog'
  });
```

It works when I refresh the page, but if this page loads from another page then it won't work. I don't know what causes this.

Page code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="users">

    <div data-role="header">

        <h1 id="userheader">IM Messenger</h1>


        <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" id="logout">Logout</a>


    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

    <center>
        <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Peer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Group</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->



    </center>
    </div><!-- /content -->



    <div data-role="footer">
        <a href="#" id="openAddDlg" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Add Contact</a>
    </div><!-- /footer -->



</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="dialog" id="addDialog">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Send Invitation</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">

        <label for="username">JID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="addjid" id="im-addjid" value="user4@rewire.in"  />

        <label for="username">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="addname"  id="im-addname" value="user4"  />

        <a href="#" id="sendInvitation" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Send</a>

      </div>


</div> <!-- dialog add contact -->
```

Comment: Because you're using single page model (multi HTML files). In this case, jQM **cant** load more than one page in each HTML file. It works when you refresh, as that HTML becomes first page and acts as multi-page model (multi pages in one html).

Comment: Where is the dialog in your code? If it's there, is it enhanced? (you can see using [Firequery](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firequery/) in Firebug). Seems to me it's not, so try calling `$(document).enhanceWithin()` in JQM 1.4 once you append anything dynamcially to the DOM

Comment: @frequent dialog is already there starts with `<div data-role="dialog" id="addDialog">`

Comment: @Omar then what should i do ?|

Comment: add your dialog in dialog.html for example and call it using `mobile.changePage("dialog.html", {role: dialog, transition: "pop"})`.

Comment: yeah i tried that to , but in that case when my dialog gets closed and i append some item to a list then the item in the old list get vanished

Comment: which old list? could you please elaborate?

Comment: yeah actually the page contains the list items when i click on a button a dialog appears and when the dialog gets closed , i am appending list item in existing listview ` `$("#chatList").append("<li>test</li").listview("refresh");` but the new item doesnt appear

Comment: @Hunt: ah the magic of scrolling... as your dialog is **outside** of the page, you need to enhance it by yourself, because JQM only enhances what's inside. So `$(document).enhanceWithin();` on `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: if you want to simplify things, use a _popup_. If you still want a dialog, you can append items to previous page once dialog is closed `pagehide`.

Comment: for that `enchanceWithin` i have to move to `JQM 1.4`

Comment: @frequent does jQM 1.4 support single page with multi-pages? that would be great. I haven't tried it yet.